# plot_ly doesn't recognize column names

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to get started with plot.ly and here is an extremely stupid question. I made a plot.ly account and linked my username and API key to it in RStudio. I typed the following in Rstudio, as given on the plotly setting started page,

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, text = paste("Clarity: ", clarity),
        mode = "markers", color = carat, size = carat)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, text = paste("Clarity: ", clarity),  : 
  object 'carat' not found
```

The same type of error arises with other common dataframes in R (e.g mtcars, etc).

Comment: You can get the column names either by running `attach(d)` before running the `plot_ly` function or by loading the `ggplot` package at the top of your script (that's where the `diamonds` dataset is).

Comment: @Abdou That works! Thank you!

Comment: `attach` is generally considered bad practice. It's better to wrap things in `with`, though here you shouldn't even need to do that if `d` is getting assigned correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to breaking changes / improvements in Plotly 4.0: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/NEWS.md#breaking-changes--improvements

The above code requires formulas instead of plain expression. For example:

`plot_ly(d, x = ~carat, y = ~price, text = ~paste("Clarity: ", clarity),
        mode = "markers", color = ~carat, size = ~carat)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Seems that is a **bug** with the latest version of plotly 4.3.1.
If you install the [CRAN version (3.6.0)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotly/index.html) the columns are picked properly.